# Are my MetaMask account addresses fixed once and for all for the same seed?

Tags: metamask

I have three Accounts in my MetaMask wallet chrome extension.

Suppose I remove the MetaMask extension altogether from my laptop and on another laptop I install a fresh MetaMask with the same seed and create another two accounts.

Will these three accounts have the same `0x...` hash addresses as the three accounts that were originally on the other laptop?

Or will all three be completely different addresses?

I'm guessing they'll be the same but just worried that they won't - in case I ever delete the MetaMask chrome extension for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the seed phrase for the account will bring all the accounts.  They won't be there immediately but if you add new account it'll bring them in the order they were created.  Think of them as your seed phrases children.

Your seed phrase "keys" also work in ANY Ethereum wallet.  You can import them into a coinbase extension wallet or trust wallet or Binance Chain wallet and all your coins will be there.

Comment: Wow, so I dont have to use meta mask and could try one of the other wallets you mention.

Comment: Your mnemonic phrase is all you need to use any other wallet.  Took me a while to figure it out too!